# Data Structure to efficiently merge data for CSV Writing

Tags: java, data-structures, merge, export-to-csv

I've been stuck on this for a few hours now and would love some help. Im trying to make a CSV file in Java to track covid cases per case type per province in Canada, but I'm running into an issue. Essentially I need to have the CSV with the headers of "Date", "Province", "Confirmed", "Deaths", "Active". I am able to obtain the data for a specific case type("Deaths", or "Confirmed", or "Active"), but im unsure of what data structure to use to efficiently add it into a table or matrix. I've thought of using a HASHTABLE or HASHMAP, but the issue becomes what would i use as my value as dates will appear twice and province is obtained from the set. Some advice on what data structure to efficiently implement this would be great. I obtain the data as a JSON using this API: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc?version=latest , and I can pull the data for specific dates and case types. I just cant think of a good way to merge the data together without having to do it linearly over everything. I'm thinking of maybe using a HASHSET, but i dont think this will work. Where i parse the case type individually, then merge each set together, so that duplicated values don't appear, append this into a JTABLE, then move on to the next object. I know that the lengths of each array that has my data are the same.
[Example of Data for Recovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EQuM.png). I have two other data sets that look like this. [Full data for Recovered](https://api.covid19api.com/country/canada/status/recovered/live?from=2020-05-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-05-02T00:00:00Z)

I'm doing this in Java if it helps, and Im using Unirest to perform the HTTP get request.

Comment: Why not using a database ? It would allow all the flexibility required without needing to think it though.

Comment: Would H2 be a good idea? and just write the values associated with the hashmap to each column

Comment: I don't know H2, and to be honest I have a rather superficial knowledge of dbs. But from the description you made of your requirements, it seems that the db format would do all you need to do, and on top of it allow for further refinement if they were one day needed. I'd say that since the task would be rather simple and the amount of data rather small, the best tool for that is the one you feel comfortable with already.